# JavaScript FF IE Update + message script issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scripting

I have this ajax_update script that updates file.php every 60 seconds.. 
Now file.php outputs this after updated a table:

```
<div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span>Hey, <b><? echo $userid; ?></b>, You've got +1 points, you now have <u>
    <? echo $n["points"]; ?></u></span>
    <a href="#" class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice()">X</a>
</div>
<script> 
$("#message").fadeIn("slow");
</script>
```

Why will this only work in FF, i mean appear, but not in IE..

What I am trying to do is that after file.php have updated a field in the database(points), there will come up a message like stackoverflow at the top(just like when you earn a badge) saying that you have received 1 point.

This works perfectly in FF but in IE, the message is not showing at all?

Maybe another way to do this? Or a fix, solution?

I tried to put the little JS script in the index.php and remove the ajax update thing, and it works fine in IE.

```
function addpoints()  { 
        var userid = document.getElementById('user_id_points');
        var postFile    =   'addpoints.php?userid='+ userid.value;
  $.post(postFile, function(data){  
  $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#points").html(data); 
    setTimeout(addpoints, 62000);
  });
}    

function closeNotice() {
    $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

my ajax script^

```
<?php
include "tilslut.php";
$userid = $_GET["userid"];
$s = mysql_query("SELECT points, lastpoint FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'");
$n = mysql_fetch_array($s);
$tid = time(); 
mysql_query("UPDATE member_profile set points = points+1, lastpoint=$tid  WHERE lastpoint<=$tid-60 AND user_id = '".$userid."'");
if(isset($userid)) {
$e = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'");
$f = mysql_fetch_array($e);
echo $n["points"];
}elseif (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
$s = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'");
$n = mysql_fetch_array($s);
?>
If you receive this text, no problem with php
<div id="message"  onclick="closeNotice()">this works
</div>
<?
}else{
?>
This doesnt work at all
<?
}
?>
```

my php coding, with the

Comment: Can you see the message in IE when you remove the `display:none`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
in the top in addpoints.php

Answer (score 2):

In your ajax update script, call this after the results are in:

```
$("#message").fadeIn("slow");
```

Scripts coming back as part of the request are unreliable, putting the logic in your ajax result function is a better approach in this case.

Try this for your ajax call:

```
function addpoints()  { 
  var postFile = 'addpoints.php?userid='+ $('#user_id_points').val();
  $.post(postFile, function(data){
    $("#points").html(data).find("#message").fadeIn("slow")
    setTimeout(addpoints, 62000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Now it does work, but it only appears if i have a <div id="message">test</div> in index.php, and not file.php, like i wants to? How do i solve that?

Comment: @providerazzzyh - Can you post the code that fetches the ajax page?  I could help a lot better with that code

Comment: Okay ive added my ajax script and the php file that its updating

Comment: @providerazzzyh -Try the updated answer...before you were trying to show `#message` before it was added, this should wait until it's in the document and ready to do.

Comment: @Nick Craver- i tried the new answer, and it works great in FF, but doesnt appear in IE..

Comment: I just tried to put the <div> box in index.php and then remove the ajax updating script and then putted  $("#message").fadeIn("slow"); under document ready function, and then it worked in IE..
But ofcourse thats not how i wanted, but i now know that it works with document ready function and not if its in the addpoints() function. Although it works in FF doing it with addpoints().. Its like in IE, it doesnt want to use #message from addpoints.php..? Hope you can help me out, im pretty lost :(

Comment: @Azzyh - This sounds like a more global problem, can you run your outputted html through the w3c validators, see if there's some unclosed tag or ID problem?  Things like this make IE act real funny.  http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: okay, so i did like you said and i ran my site through validator.w3.org, i got 102 erros, and i've solved out them all.. BUT STILL nothing in IE. http://azzyh.dk/newgen/area/member/indextest.php check it out here, it will work in FF but not IE! (ive set the timeout to 3000, thats why its going OK fast in FF).

Comment: @Azzyh - You have a javascript error, in your body onload tag `MM_preloadImages(....` look at `images/index_10.gif`, it's not wrapped in quotes completely, it has `'images/index_10.gif`, needs to be `'images/index_10.gif'`.  Fixing that should get you going.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Okay, so i fixed that. BUT still not appearing, this seems to be really hard for IE?

Comment: @Azzyh - Works fine in IE8 here, just needs some styling work, but the messages appear in the left-hand bar header.